# How to configure PyBuilder to look locally for certain files needed for testing?

Tags: python, build-tools, pybuilder

My tests use two CSV files as a large part of my program involves interpreting and then posting data to elasticsearch. When running PyBuilder, it can't find these files since it's running from a different directory. For example, one of the errors I get is this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PythonUtilities-1.0-py3.6.egg/tests/in/data.csv'
```

How can I configure PyBuilder in a way that allows me to work with the files that are in the same directory as my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a Manifest.in file to specify what files Pybuilder should add.